# Getting list of specific attributes for all Hyper-V VMs on Windows Server

Tags: powershell, scripting, hyper-v

Let's start off on the right foot.  I'm not looking for someone to write the script discussed below for us.  What I'd like is a pointer or pointers that can quickly get me up to speed on just the PowerShell parts I *need* in order to accomplish this task without first becoming an expert in PowerShell and then in use of Get-VM.  That said, please read on.

We are attempting to do a virtual machine inventory on several VM hosts in a network of computers.  To that end, we would like to write a script that writes a .CSV file containing the host name, and specific attributes for each VM defined on that host.  So, for example:

```
    HostName, VMName, ComputerName, ID,                Maximum memory, Minimum meomry, ...
    VMH1,     VM1,    DATACENTER1,  54324ebe-f167-..., 1099511627776, 536870912, ...
```

and so on, for each VM under this host... and we'd run the command on each of our hosts to get the inventory into files we could merge for an enterprise view.

Where I need help, is with PowerShell scripting.  I'm highly skilled with KornShell and many other scripting languages, but I've avoided PS all these years.  Now the piper is at my door.

Trying to understand how to tie these two things together:
 I can get a list of VMs with the

```
Get-VM | ft Name
```

Given a VM, I can get the details I want with

```
Get-VM <vmname> | 
Select-Object Name, etc...
```

I believe I'd need to pipe the  command into the  command, but that's not working for me.  And then once that's done, need to manipulate the output so that %COMPUTERNAME% is at the front of the output, so a simple Export-Csv won't work for us either.

Again, I don't want this to be a "here's my homework - do it for me" entry; just looking for pointers.

THanks for your time.

Comment: Please add the code of what you have tried so far and which _specific_ problems you have (any error message or output that is not as expected). "Not working" isn't a very good problem description. ;-)

Comment: What I meant was, I tried 'Get-VM | ForEach-Object Get-VM | Select-Object *" (no quotes) and got no output.  Next, I tried "Get-VM | ft Name| ForEach-Object Get-VM | Select-Object *" (still no output).  Again, what I need to do is to output the results of each Get-VM <name> | Select-Object <list,of,objects> to individual files (one for each server), with THIS server name also as a column in the output.

Comment: Always, with code updates, put them in your original post so that are more easily followed, readable, etc. Yet, what you have here in the comment is syntactically incorrect. You are way over-complicating this. VM's notwithstanding, this is Powershell day 1 kind of stuff. Meaning, pick an object (say processes) and loop to give me the details one can select from. This is no different than getting inventory from a physical machine via ADDS. Tons of pre-built examples all over SO and the web. Use the So search box above or your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of what you are after are in the examples in the PowerShell Help Files for that cmdlet.

```
# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Get-VM).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Get-VM).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Get-VM -Examples
# Results
<#
Get-VM -ComputerName Server1 | 
Where-Object {$_.State -eq 'Running'}


Get-ClusterGroup | 
Where {$PSItem.GroupType -eq 'VirtualMachine' } | 
Get-VM
#>
Get-help -Name Get-VM -Full
Get-help -Name Get-VM -Online
```

As for your code in the comment section, this ...

```
Get-VM | 
ForEach-Object Get-VM | 
Select-Object *
```

and/or this ...

```
Get-VM | 
ft Name| 
ForEach-Object Get-VM | 
Select-Object *
```

... both are syntactically wrong. If you use the PowerShell_ISE or VSCode editor they would immediately flag these as errors.  If you are prone to staying in the console host, then use the `Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer` cmdlet to check your code and `Trace-Command` to see all it is doing. See the help file for details.

```
(Get-Command -Name Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer -Examples
Get-help -Name Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer -Full
Get-help -Name Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer -Online


(Get-Command -Name Trace-Command).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Trace-Command).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Trace-Command -Examples
Get-help -Name Trace-Command -Full
Get-help -Name Trace-Command -Online
```

Thus should be this

```
Get-VM | 
ForEach-Object {
    $PSItem | 
    Select-Object -Property '*'
}
```

Never do `'*'` for all properties, unless that is what you really want. Always select only what you need.

To see all the properties of on the first VM, just to this

```
(Get-VM)[0] | 
Select-Object -Property '*'
```

To see all the properties of all the VM's, just remove the `[0]`.

You easily leverage the `Out-GtidView` cmdlet for selecting VM and viewing details.

```
(Get-VM)[0] | 
Select-Object -Property '*' | 
Out-GridView -Title 'Showing Virtual Machines'
```

see:

- https://mcpmag.com/articles/2016/02/17/creating-a-gui-using-out-gridview.aspx
- https://spiderzebra.com/2020/05/26/utilizing-powershell-out-gridview-as-a-gui-alternative
- https://mikefrobbins.com/2014/09/11/creating-a-simplistic-gui-interface-with-out-gridview

Lastly, you are also saying, you want a list of VMHosts, that you are then trying to get the VM Guest off those hosts. That is not what Get-VM is for.

If your VMHosts are Windows Servers, joined to your domain, you'd use `Get-ADComputer` to get a list of VMHost names (however you have them named), then pass that to Get-VM to get the guests.

Example:

```
Get-ADComputer -Identity 'VMHost*' | 
ForEach-Object {Get-VM -ComputerName $PSitem}
```

If they are not windows machines, use your chosen method to get that hostname, then pass that to `Get-VM`.

Doing this on my local Hyper-V machine

```
$env:COMPUTERNAME, 'Localhost' | 
ForEach {
    Get-VM -ComputerName $PSItem |
    Select-Object -Property Name, State, Status, Version
}
# Results
<#
Name     State Status             Version
----     ----- ------             -------
WS2K16     Off Operating normally 9.0    
... 
#>


$env:COMPUTERNAME, 'Localhost' | 
ForEach-Object {
    $VMHostName = $PSItem
    Get-VM -ComputerName $VMHostName | 
    Select-Object -Property @{
        Name       = 'VMHost'
        Expression = {$VMHostName }
    }, Name, State, Status, Version | 
    Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Temp\VMGuestReport.Csv' -Append 
}

Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Temp\VMGuestReport.Csv' | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#
VMHost    Name   State   Status             Version
------    ----   -----   ------             -------
SRV1      WS2K16 Off     Operating normally 9.0    
...   
Localhost WS2K16 Off     Operating normally 9.0    
...
#>
```